# Powershell - Get compatibility from SPweb

Tags: powershell, version

I want to do a simple task, I made a script who get all followed site from a user.
But I want to filter it with compatibilitylevel.

With few sites, it's Ok, I do :

```
$currentSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteFollowed.Uri.AbsoluteUri
if($currentSite.CompatibilityLevel -eq 15){
   #...
}
```

But with many sites, it's not Ok because I get SPWeb too... So I have this error :

```
Get-SPSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url:
```

When I replace Get-SPSite by Get-SPWeb, I can get this site but I can't get compatibilitylevel....

```
Object SPSite :
Url                                                     CompatibilityLevel  
---                                                     ------------------  
https://site.fr/sites/test               15                  

Object SPWeb :
Url                                                    
---                                                    
https://site.domain.fr/sites/Collec_SRO/en...
```

=> No compatibilityLevel...

Do you have an idea to get the sharepoint version? (2010/2013, 14/15)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$currentSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteFollowed.Uri.AbsoluteUri

  foreach($web in $currentSite.AllWebs){
   $web.Url version is $web.UIVersion #4 or 15
  }
}
```

Comment: Last question, how to determine with powershell if a Sharepoint site is a SPSite object or SPWeb?

Comment: if you use Get-SPWeb <URL> successfully, then it is an SPWeb. However all site collections will have a rootweb.

Comment: Thanks but if you do this, you had an error, you can't test URL without instanciation?

Comment: Check this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/powershell-and-checking-for-site-existence

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetType()` method

```
$web.GetType().Name
```

If it is web it gives you `SPWeb` otherwise `SPSite`

Comment: Thanks but to test "GetType()" you need to have an object.
My problem is I want to know before instanciation if URL is SPSite or SPWeb, otherwise I had an error